# DataTable Seems To Lose Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, datatable, webforms

Am I over-writing the datatable when I think I am adding columns to it?  I know that if I write to the output window in my _FinishButton() event my results are there, but when I write to output in my pushdatatosql() method it is empty.  I have the Datatable desclared as a class variable.

What am I incorrectly coding here?

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();

protected void FinishBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pushdatatosql();
}

protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow dr = null;
    dtResult.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("mainevent", typeof(string)));
    dtResult.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("secondevent", typeof(string)));

    foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdOther.Rows)
    {
        dr = dtResult.NewRow();
        TextBox box1 = (TextBox)gr.Cells[1].FindControl("txtmainevent");
        TextBox box2 = (TextBox)gr.Cells[2].FindControl("txtse");

        dr["mainevent"] = box1.Text;
        dr["secondevent"] = box2.Text;

        dtResult.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
}


protected void pushdatatosql()
{
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in dtResult.Rows)
    {
        foreach (var item in dataRow.ItemArray)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SQLString"].ConnectionString))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
        {
            foreach (DataColumn c in dtResult.Columns)
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(c.ColumnName, c.ColumnName);

            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "TestInsertTable";
                bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtResult);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @mason - how would you recommend I do such?

Comment: Scratch my previous statement about not using DataTables. I scrolled down and see you're using SqlBulkCopy. That's a legitimate use for DataTables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dtResult` class variable you refer to only lasts for as long as the request. So for each post-back you make in your page, a new instance of this class and that class member will be created. In Webforms the *"Unload event is raised after the page has been fully rendered, sent to the client, and is ready to be discarded."* [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx). At this point your class variable is destroyed, along with any values it holds.

To resolve this you can try to store your values instead in the view state. Which [persists across requests](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: So in winforms this would be perfectly acceptable, but since this is webforms I have to use view state?

Comment: Correct, the life cycle in Windows forms allows you to store values in the class which persist across events. Because Webforms is web application, this works differently.

Comment: would viewstate or session variable be my best bet for saving the datatable?

Comment: @BoJackHorseman You don't need to use ViewState, you can use Session, a database, or any persistence mechanism.

Comment: @Crowcoder these would also work. There are many ways around this problem. It is almost always a *gotcha* that every new WebForms developer comes across

Comment: @MichaelHancock - can I still use sqlbulkcopy with a viewstate?

Comment: Once you have got your values back from the ViewState (or any of the other state storage methods other commentators have suggested) and into your function you can still use `sqlbulkcopy`.